# Flutter: Prevent some children from getting stretched

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Do you have an idea on how to prevent child from getting stretched.

```
Column(
 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: [
   Container(child: ...),
   Row( // idon't want this child to be stretched
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
     FlatButton(
       child: Icon(Icons.add),
       onPressed: () {},
       color: Color(0xFFE2EDE4),
     ),
     Text(
      '$quantity',
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5.copyWith(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
     ),
     FlatButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.remove),
      onPressed: () {},
      color: Color(0xFFE2EDE4),
     ),
    ],
   ),
  ],
);
```

I tried to wrap it in ConstrainedBox but still it is being stretched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch property of Column don't affect to Row child. Instead of using mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween

You can add SizedBox(width: ...)

Answer (score 1):

If you want stretch Row widget, how about remove 'mainAxisAlignment' of Row.
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Container(height: 200, color: Colors.blue, child: Text('123'),),
          Column(
        
            children: <Widget> [
             Row( // idon't want this child to be stretched
           
            children: [
              FlatButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.add),
                onPressed: () {},
                color: Color(0xFFE2EDE4),
              ),
              Text(
                'qweqe',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5.copyWith(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.remove),
                onPressed: () {},
                color: Color(0xFFE2EDE4),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          ]),
         
        ],
      );

    }
}
```